# How do I make my tweet button pull a string from my page into a newly composed tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

My codepen - http://codepen.io/illpill/pen/VbeVEq

For the sake of stacks policy, here is an example of code

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-md pull-right" id="tweetButton">Tweet This</button>
```

My question is, how do I have it pull the quote from the page and compose it into a readily made tweet with added hashtags?

Comment: That's HTML. HTML is not code, it's markup that describes visual layout and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by adding a unique class to your Tweet button, then when someone clicks that button, get the current quote and pass it into a Tweet URL:

```
function tweet(message) {
  window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=hashtagshere&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message));
}

$('button.tweet').click(function() {
  var currQuote = $('#quote').text();
  tweet(currQuote);
});
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwqzpz)

Comment: This is a great start. Thanks. I'm going to try and make it so that it edits the quote when it is too long. I'll come back if I need help. Thanks!